# Python - Word Count script

Tags: python, wc

Down below is Python word count script that I found online, I am having difficulty understanding how you would run this though. Would I need to create a file and open it in Python before running this program for it to work?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    data = sys.stdin.read()
    chars = len(data)
    words = len(data.split())
    lines = len(data.split('\n'))

    print ("{0}   {1}   {2}".format(lines, words, chars))
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: python wordcount.py < your-text-file.txt

Comment: is there a reason not to use `wc` utility?

Comment: thanks, @Ashalynd. Well wc utility is just too easy Sebastian =D

Comment: Like @J.F.Sebastian says, why not simply use wc -l your-text-file.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sys.stdin.read()` line tells me that it is expecting to receive the input from the standard input so you can use it something like:

```
type somefile.txt | python wordcount.py
```

or run `python wordcount.py` and type into the console ending with ctrl-d

Comment: `python wordcount.py <somefile.txt`

Answer (score 2):

`sys.stdin.read()` reads data from the console. Just run the python program and type whatever you want. When you're done press `Ctrl + D`.